# How to add data to remote DB?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, server

https://github.com/mitchtabian/LoginAndRegister

i have just changed the urlRegistration and urlLogin variables in BackgroundTask Class from "http://tabian.ca/LoginAndRegister-register.php" to my "http://lmonstergirl.0fees.us/LoginAndRegister-register.php".

database is same as the project.

whenever i want to register anyone, i get "successfully registered *user*" message but it only adds the id, other rows are blank.

[image]

code is same and my php files are below. This

```
<?php
require "LoginAndRegister-connection.php";

$user_name = $_POST["identifier_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["identifier_password"];
$user_email = $_POST["identifier_email"];

//test variables
//$user_name = "Ron";
//$user_pass = "ronspassword";
//$user_email = "ron@tabian.ca";



$query = "INSERT INTO login (name,email,password) VALUES ('$user_name','$user_email','$user_pass')";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
echo "<h2>Data Successfully Inserted!</h2>";
}
else{
    echo "<h2>Data was unable to be inserted into database :(.</h2>";
}



?>
```

but when I change my php to this

```
<?php
require "LoginAndRegister-connection.php";

//$user_name = $_POST["identifier_name"];
//$user_pass = $_POST["identifier_password"];
//$user_email = $_POST["identifier_email"];

//test variables
$user_name = "Ron";
$user_pass = "ronspassword";
$user_email = "ron@tabian.ca";



$query = "INSERT INTO login (name,email,password) VALUES ('$user_name','$user_email','$user_pass')";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
    echo "<h2>Data Successfully Inserted!</h2>";
}
else{
    echo "<h2>Data was unable to be inserted into database :(.</h2>";
}



?>
```

it adds to db

[image]

i also tried to change $_POST to $_GET and still added blank.

here is my log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: applications.loginandregister, PID: 3893
                 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@12b6e281 is not valid; is your activity running?
                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:576)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:306)
                     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:987)
                     at applications.loginandregister.BackgroundTask.display(BackgroundTask.java:183)
                     at applications.loginandregister.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:169)
                     at applications.loginandregister.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:29)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

i have only changed the urls in the code but there you go:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

Context context;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
    this.context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("flag","0");
    editor.commit();

    String urlRegistration = "http://lmonstergirl.0fees.us/LoginAndRegister-register.php";
    String urlLogin  = "http://lmonstergirl.0fees.us/LoginAndRegister-login.php";
    String task = params[0];

    if(task.equals("register")){
        String regName = params[1];
        String regEmail = params[2];
        String regPassword = params[3];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlRegistration);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
            String myData = URLEncoder.encode("identifier_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regName,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("identifier_email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regEmail,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("identifier_password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regPassword,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(myData);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStream.close();

            editor.putString("flag","register");
            editor.commit();
            return "Successfully Registered " + regName;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    if(task.equals("login")){
        String loginEmail = params[1];
        String loginPassword = params[2];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlLogin);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            //send the email and password to the database
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
            String myData = URLEncoder.encode("identifier_loginEmail","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(loginEmail,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("identifier_loginPassword","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(loginPassword,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(myData);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //get response from the database
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String dataResponse = "";
            String inputLine = "";
            while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                dataResponse += inputLine;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            System.out.println(dataResponse);

            editor.putString("flag","login");
            editor.commit();
            return  dataResponse;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

//This method willbe called when doInBackground completes... and it will return the completion string which
//will display this toast.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    String flag = preferences.getString("flag","0");

    if(flag.equals("register")) {
        Toast.makeText(context,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if(flag.equals("login")){
        String test = "false";
        String name = "";
        String email = "";
        String[] serverResponse = s.split("[,]");
        test = serverResponse[0];
        name = serverResponse[1];
        email = serverResponse[2];

        if(test.equals("true")){
            editor.putString("name",name);
            editor.commit();
            editor.putString("email",email);
            editor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,LogginIn.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            display("Login Failed...", "That email and password do not match our records :(.");
        }
    }else{
        display("Login Failed...","Something weird happened :(.");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

public void display(String title, String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
}
```

---

```
public class LogginIn extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView name,email;
SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logged_in_layout);

    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textEmail);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textName);
    preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String mName = preferences.getString("name","ERROR getting name");
    String mEmail = preferences.getString("email","ERROR getting email");
    name.setText(mName);
    email.setText(mEmail);
}
}
```

---

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etName, etEmail, etPassword;
String name, email, password;
Button btnRegister;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_layout);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewName);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewEmail);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewRegister);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = etName.getText().toString();
            email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            String task = "register";
            BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(Register.this);
            backgroundTask.execute(task,name, email, password);
            finish();
        }
    });


}
}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnRegister, btnLogin;
EditText etEmail,etPassword;
String stringEmail,stringPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stringEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
            stringPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();
            String task = "login";
            BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(MainActivity.this);

            etEmail.setText("");
            etPassword.setText("");

            //execute the task
            //passes the paras to the backgroundTask (param[0],param[1],param[2])
            backgroundTask.execute(task,stringEmail,stringPassword);
        }
    });

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Nothing much wrong with the code. Are you sure you have the urls in the right place?

Comment: could it be because of some errors on $_POST about server?

Comment: You get the Android exception so that's where you should find a problem. To make sure PHP is okay, create sample PHP form where you can input data and submit it using POST method.

Comment: i have added the android code, you may want to take a look

Comment: i have created a php form and i can see the $_post variables by vardump, but cannot add to db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found out that the web server i am using has some issues. i basically made a form and added register.php as its action. tried on my local server and worked fine for both android device and pc. then i added that form to web server and worked fine for pc but added blank texts again for android. post array is empty when trying to connect from android device.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting to stackoverflow!

Because your test variables work, you know it's not the php. The problem is almost 100% lying in the android code. Please post your android code.

Comment: i have added the android code, you may want to take a look

Comment: I'm not too sure, it seems to be working but it's posting null Strings to the database. Are you getting any kind of an error message? What about the manifest code? Is it correct? Is your database text set to UTF-8?

Comment: unfortunately yes, same as yours in tutorial. i am thinking that source of the problem is the web host